# How to group Japanese and other non-Latin names in LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, internationalization, longlistselector

If you put your Windows Phone Emulator or device into Japanese, Korean, or other non latin languages and use the people app, their implementation of the LongListSelector shows Japanese grouping characters, then a unicode "globe with meridians" character, followed by a-z characters:

[image: WP7 People App]  [image: WP7 People App]

With the LongListSelector from the Windows Phone toolkit, you have to do your own manual grouping logic.  How do I get the list of Japanese/Korean/etc name grouping characters and how do I determine what grouping character a name goes under (since looking at my 2nd screenshot, the grouping character is nowhere in the users name)?

Comment: マ (ma) means the same thing as ま, the first character in the name shown. The difference is that grouping character is katakana, while the other one is hiragana. Both are syllabaries used to write Japanese, and while they have different purposes (katakana is mainly used for loanwords), you would want to treat them identically for this sort of grouping. I can't say why it's using katakana instead of hiragana for the grouping headers, but I see nothing wrong in either picture.

Comment: Also note that it's not grouping by character, but by "initial sound" - the part that goes before the vowel. This is a common way of organizing things in Japanese, due to the way these syllabaries work.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you add 96 to the unicode value of hiragana (ま) to get the equivalent katakana (マ).

You can determine if a character is hiragana by checking that it's unicode value falls in the range 3040-309F.

Unfortunately, as Noah mentions, many names are spelt using kanji: an alphabet of about 40,000 characters each with hiragana equivalents and many contextual to their surroundings. If you want to support those, you'll need to look for a Japanese language library to help you.

FYI, katakana is occasionally used to represent CAPITAL letters so that would explain their usage here. (Given Metro's lowercase preference, I would have thought katakana a better fit).

If you only want to support hiragana, here's something that should help:

```
const int KatakanaStartCode = 0x30A0;
const int HiraganaStartCode = 0x3040;
const int HiraganaEndCode = 0x309F;

private char GetGroupChar(string name)
{
    // Check for null/blank
    // Check for numbers, etc

    char firstChar = name[0];
    int firstCharCode = (int)firstChar;

    bool isHiragana = (HiraganaStartCode <= firstCharCode && 
        firstCharCode <= HiraganaEndCode);

    if (isHiragana)
    {
        char katakanaChar = (char)(firstCharCode + 
            (KatakanaStartCode - HiraganaStartCode));

        return katakanaChar;
    }

    return Char.ToLowerInvariant(firstChar);
}
```

And then:

```
string name = "またな たなかあ";

char s = GetGroupChar(name);

Debug.WriteLine(s); // マ
```

Comment: And then for the other languages like Korean, Chinese, etc I have to figure out their grouping logic?  Which may not match how the phone OS does it?  Hopefully Microsoft releases some kind of contact picker that has this built in.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It might be worth looking around for a library that handles this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about the Windows Phone Toolkit in particular, but basically, it works like this:  Most Japanese names will have a Kanji form (which is normally how it is written, and what is displayed).  Since the Kanji form may have ambiguous pronunciation, there are fields for pronunciation as well.  You use the pronunciation field to group the names.  (And you can group any names without data in the pronunciation field into another "other" group).

For example:
Kanji: 山本次郎
katakana:ヤマモトジロウ

Then your "grouping chars" are just a list (or partial list) of Katakana or Hiragana, and this guy would fall under "や" or "ヤ".